# git tfs checkin tool says 'nothing to commit' when I know there are changes in my master branch and tfs/default

Tags: git, tfs

I have just recently started git-tfs bridge and seems to work fine for a while until recently:

Here is my workflow:
1) git tfs clone 
2) I create my working_branch 
3) git checkout working_branch 
4) I start to make changes and then I commit)
5) I do a git checkout master, git merge working_branch
6) then do a git tfs checkintool

On the checkin though, I only select a few files and not everything.

7) then I do a git tfs fetch and git rebase tfs/default

How do I commit those files that I unchecked in my previous commit, because it now thinks that there is no commit and it seem tfs/default and master are the same and no changes

Comment: Did you try merging from your working_branch again?  Or cherry-picking the not-in-TFS commits from working branch to master?

Comment: git status says, my master is up to date when I go a git tfs fetch and git tfs rebase tfs/default. I'm wondering if it's because git tfs does a merge commit so when I unchecked some files when commiting it now thinks tfs/default has now been merged with my master even though there are some files in my master that were not commited to tfs/default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do

> **git add** filename

or git add dir/wildcard before you can commit anything to the local repository.

Answer (score 2):

According to [explanation](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/git-tfs-dev/ybkhKGp0aRg/discussion) on git-tfs group, git tfs checkintool is not supposed to be used for partial checkins (and might even lead to losing modifications in files you chose not to commit):

> Checkintool is just a convenient tool to make last minute review of your changes and is not supposed to select things to checkin. If you need to divide changes into two chunks - use git's features that is *much* more powerful than TFS's ones. For example, if you want to divide commit in two, do a soft reset to previous commit and commit things to two commits. Then execute git tfs rcheckin and you'll have these two commits in the TFS as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it looks that the checkin tool actually reverted the changes in git. There is probably a better way to do this, but this is what I did:

- I made a cloned repository of my local git
- Then I checked out the particular version that before the tfs tool made the changes
- Copied over all files I originally unchecked in the tfs tool (I used the Total Commander's synchronize dirs tool)
- Committed in git
- Used the checkin tool to commit to tfs